# SI tools for SDI video signals

Tags: video

I am designing a board with high speed HD-SDI signals. The data is single ended HD-SDI. There are circuits which convert it into differential HD-SDI followed by another circuit that converts it into single ended HD-SDI. Now, before going into layout I would like to simulate it for any signal integrity issues. Is Microwave Office a good tool for such an analysis? This is just a preliminary doubt. Any other open source tools that can do the same?

Comment: This is a shopping question. Off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a shopping question!

That said, for 3G-SDI I would probably not bother simulating it, by the time you get the connector model really right (And how would you be sure) you may as well just prototype the relevant bits and measure them (12G is a whole other ball game).

Don't forget that SDI extends pretty much down to DC on the pathologicals so your simulation runs will take some time, but I see no reason to think MWO could not do it.

Keep the layout compact, trace length you don't have does not cause you problems.

Most of the line equaliser parts have suggested layouts in the datasheets, and the eval board documentation will usually give you a workable layer stack.

Oh yea, be careful about that 4.7uF coupling capacitor and its pad geometry, you often want to knock a cutout in the L2 ground plane to reduce the parasitic cap.

You will need access to something that measures physical layer eye and both timing and alignment jitter, none of which are exactly cheap.

Comment: I would also note that the variation of dielectric constant across frequency for the PCB can be a far more important consideration than is always recognised. There are some (reasonably priced) materials that have minimal variation from 100MHz to 10GHz.